# JavaScript appendChild function not working for an img element made with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently, I was working on a website and ran into a problem. I wanted to make an *img* element in JS, but found out that once I gave the element an *src* I could not use the function appendChild. I am wondering if there is something I am doing wrong, or if the way I am trying to do this is actually impossible. Thanks!

```
let clear = document.getElementById("clear");
let pfp = document.getElementById("pfp");
let unitrep = [];

function cl() {
    unitrep = document.createElement("img");
    document.unitrep.src = "dirt.jpg";
    document.unitrep.alt = "Dirt";
    pfp.appendChild(unitrep);
    unitrep.id = "land";
}

clear.onclick = cl;
```

Comment: `document.unitrep.scr` should be: `document.unitrep.src` (short for source)

Comment: You're also declaring `unitrep` as an empty array, but then overriding that within your function as being a reference to the new `img` element.

Comment: And, `unitrep` isn't a property of `document`, so you should have just `unitrep.src`, `unitrep.alt`, and `unitrep.id`, not with `document.` in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using src instead of scr.

Scr doesn’t exist.

Comment: We don't typically answer questions that are just simple typos because they are likely to get closed as such. For that we just add a comment.

Comment: Ok sorry I won’t do it again

Comment: Lol I was really breaking my brains to find whats wrong, turns out its a typo.